# Notebook to write Java jobs for Spark

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin

I am writing my first Spark job using Java API.

I want to run it using a notebook.

I am looking into Zeppelin and Jupyter.

At Zeppelin documentation I see support for Scala, IPySpark and SparkR. It is not clear to me whether using two interpreters `%spark.sql %java` will allow me to work with Java API of Spark SQL

Jupyter has "IJava" kernel but I see no support for Spark with Java.

Are there other options?

Comment: The IJava kernel doesn't care about frameworks, so should work fine. Otherwise, Scala is close enough, no?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Regards IJava, don't I need some kind of Spark interpreter to run Spark under IJava? Will IJava be enough? Regards the language, I currently prefer Java for various reasons.

Comment: I've not used the IJava kernel, but I assume it offers ways to include classpath dependencies such as spark-core

Answer (score 1):

@Victoriia Zeppelin 0.9.0 has %java interpreter with example here
[zeppelin.apache.org](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/interpreter/java.html)

I try to start with it in GoogleCloud, but had some problems...

Answer (score 0):

use magic command `%jars path/to/spark.jar` in the IJava cell, according to the [IJava's author](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/issues/53#issuecomment-476648391)
then take a look on `import org.apache.spark.sql.*` for example